# jquery fadein html content from ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to append html content to a table "some content" that's returned from the ajax call. I would like to fade in this new content. how would i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(someContent).appendTo('table').hide().fadeIn();
```

Comment: Won't this hide the whole table then fade in the whole table and new content rather than just fading in the new content? Just double checking if that's what the OP wanted.

Comment: You also might find that using `append()` is marginally faster too » http://goo.gl/06QDb

Comment: @Chris `appendTo` returns the original object (`$(someContent)`), not the object which appends the content to (`$('table')`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery documentation for [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to append the new content with `style='display:none;'` and some `id` and then fade in after that using the id you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    ...
    success: function(data){
        $("<div>" + data + "</div>").hide().appendTo('.a-selector').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

When the callback gets called, it puts the data in a div, hides it (so it can be faded-in later), appends it somewhere and finally fades that div in.

The key here is to call the `hide()` function.